# Create IDs for each individual consecutive occurrence by group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have this data and looking for a way to assign IDs for each individual consecutive occurrence based on dates where each group (city) has different IDs sequence. I need to create two different ID types: ID1 which will account all the length and ID>1 which accounts only for length >1

```
cityID  date     val  occur  length
a      2017-2-1   9     1       1
a      2017-2-2   8     1       2
a      2017-2-3   4     1       2
a      2017-2-4   6     1       1
a      2017-2-5   8     1       3
a      2017-2-6   3     1       3
a      2017-2-8   7     1       3
a      2017-3-3   6     1       2
a      2017-3-4   7     1       2
b      2017-5-1   9     1       1
b      2017-6-2   8     1       2
b      2017-6-3   4     1       2
b      2017-5-4   6     1       1
b      2018-2-6   8     1       3
b      2018-2-7   3     1       3
b      2018-2-8   7     1       3
b      2019-3-3   6     1       2
b      2019-3-4   7     1       2
b      2020-1-8   7     1       2
b      2020-1-9   7     1       2
```

The result I am looking for the above data is like this

```
cityID  date     val  occur  length ID1  ID>1
a      2017-2-1   9     1       1    1   0
a      2017-2-2   8     1       2    2   1  
a      2017-2-3   4     1       2    2   1
a      2017-2-4   6     1       1    3   0
a      2017-2-5   8     1       3    4   2
a      2017-2-6   3     1       3    4   2
a      2017-2-8   7     1       3    4   2
a      2017-3-3   6     1       2    5   3
a      2017-3-4   7     1       2    5   3
b      2017-5-1   9     1       1    1   0
b      2017-6-2   8     1       2    2   1
b      2017-6-3   4     1       2    2   1
b      2017-5-4   6     1       1    3   0
b      2018-2-6   8     1       3    4   2
b      2018-2-7   3     1       3    4   2
b      2018-2-8   7     1       3    4   2
b      2019-3-3   6     1       2    5   3
b      2019-3-4   7     1       2    5   3
b      2020-1-8   7     1       2    6   4
b      2020-1-9   7     1       2    6   4
```

I have tried this but did not work

```
df%>% 
  group_by(cityID) %>%
  group_by(rle_id = c(0, cumsum(diff(date) != 1)), add = T)%>%
  mutate(count = row_number())%>%
  ungroup()
```

Example data

```
cityID <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
date<- c("2/1/2017","2/2/2017","2/3/2017","2/4/2017","2/5/2017","2/6/2017","2/8/2017","3/3/2017","3/4/2017","5/1/2017","6/2/2017","6/3/2017","5/4/2017","2/6/2018","2/7/2018","2/8/2018","3/3/2019","3/4/2019","1/8/2020","1/9/2020")
val<- c(9,8,4,6,8,3,7,6,7,9,8,4,6,8,3,7,6,7,7,7)
occur<- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
length<- c(1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(cityID, date, occur, length)
```

Comment: Why the last 2 values of `ID1` are 6, 6. The `length` values have not changed than the previous ones.

Comment: Because the date is different

Comment: What do you mean? date is different for every row in the dataframe. Do you mean month is different?

Comment: I meant the date is not consecutive for the last group (ID1 5 and ID1 6), so they should have different IDs. I have similar several cases occur in the same year and month.

Comment: Is it possible to insert an empty row between non-consecutive dates and run the code. If so how I can incorporate that in the original code, pls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rleid` from `data.table`. and `rle` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(cityID) %>%
  mutate(ID1 = data.table::rleid(length), 
         ID1_1 = with(rle(length), rep(cumsum(values > 1) * +(values > 1), lengths))) %>%
  ungroup

#   cityID  date     occur length   ID1 ID1_1
#   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1 a      2/1/2017     1      1     1     0
# 2 a      2/2/2017     1      2     2     1
# 3 a      2/3/2017     1      2     2     1
# 4 a      2/4/2017     1      1     3     0
# 5 a      2/5/2017     1      3     4     2
# 6 a      2/6/2017     1      3     4     2
# 7 a      2/8/2017     1      3     4     2
# 8 a      3/3/2017     1      2     5     3
# 9 a      3/4/2017     1      2     5     3
#10 b      5/1/2017     1      1     1     0
#11 b      6/2/2017     1      2     2     1
#12 b      6/3/2017     1      2     2     1
#13 b      5/4/2017     1      1     3     0
#14 b      2/6/2018     1      3     4     2
#15 b      2/7/2018     1      3     4     2
#16 b      2/8/2018     1      3     4     2
#17 b      3/3/2019     1      2     5     3
#18 b      3/4/2019     1      2     5     3
#19 b      1/8/2020     1      2     5     3
#20 b      1/9/2020     1      2     5     3
```

`rleid` increments the sequence for every different `length` value. `rle` increments the sequence only when `length` is greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you this works but the last 2 values of ID1 should be 6, 6 not 5,5. Yes they have similar length to the previous ones but thy belong to different dates. How that can be added to the code. Thanks